# How do I handle two different actions on the same form in React Router

Tags: react-router

I have the following React Ruoter routing table:

```js
const router = createBrowserRouter(
  [
    {
      path: "/",
      element: <Root />,
      errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
      loader: rootLoader,
      children: [
        {
          errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
          children: [
            { index: true, element: <Index /> },
            {
              path: "foo/:uid",
              element: <Foo />,
              loader: fooLoader,
            },
            {
              path: "foo/:uid/update",
              element: <Foo />,
              action: updateAction,
            },
            {
              path: "foo/:uid/clear",
              element: <Foo />,
              action: clearAction,
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </React.StrictMode>,
);
```

The `Foo` component is a simple Form that has 2 buttons: `Submit` and `Clear`

```js
export async function action({ request, params }) {
  console.log(`${request}`);
  return redirect(`/provider/${params.uid}`);
}

export default function Foo() {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  function handleOnClickClear(event) {
    if (!confirm("Please confirm you want to clear embeddings")) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }


  return (
    <>
    <Form action="update" method="post" id="foo-form">
          <input id="label" name="label" placeholder="Label" />
          <textarea
            id="text"
            name="text"
            placeholder="Text"
            rows="5"
            cols="80"
            wrap="soft"
            required
          ></textarea>
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
          <button
              type="submit"
              form="foo-form"
              formAction="clear"
              onClick={handleOnClickClear}
            >
              Clear
          </button>
      </Form>
    </>
  );
}
```

When the `Submit` button is clicked the `action` in the above component is called as it's specified on the router as `updateAction` (the import goes something like `import {action as updataAction} from...`)

I'd like to do something when clicking the `Clear` button that's different from the `Submit` action (for example clearing the text area, just for simplicity -- in reality the clear actually fires an API request, but clearing something on the displayed page could serve well for illustration), so I gave it `formAction="clear"` attribute which I was hoping would cause the app to send a request to the route I've specified for the `foo/:uid/clear` route. The `clearAction` code is very simple right now for debugging purposes:

```js
import { redirect } from "react-router-dom";

export async function action({ params }) {
  console.log(`Clearing provider ${params.uid}`);
  return redirect(`provider/${params.uid}`);
}
```

When I click the `Clear` button, the app ignores the action assignment in the routing table and the app fails with:

```
ErrorResponseImpl {status: 405, statusText: 'Method Not Allowed', internal: true, data: "Error: You made a POST request to \"/foo/0b3123f3-48bb-429a-874c-9d4b23320ff3\" but did not provide an `action` for route \"0-0-1\", so there is no way to handle the request.
```

So it would appear that this is not the way to go. I suspect if I split the two buttons into separate react router `Form`s things *might* start working, but is there a way to do this with a single forms and two separate buttons?

**Update:**
I think what I might need to do is binning the extra route with its action and use something like https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-fetcher to avoid navigation completely.

**Update2:** using the `fetcher.Form` has the same (or at least similar) effect as that above -- somehow the React Router fails to route the request to the `Foo` `action` and fails with

```
Error: You made a POST request to "/foo/f6799ce3-7b13-46e0-98bd-334f1edb49ce" but did not provide an `action` for route "0-0-1", so there is no way to handle the request.
```

I'd expect this to be "routed" to the same app route and thus handled by the `action` on that route: `updateAction` alas, no.

Comment: I suggest you to read more about handling forms, especially about "uncontrolled inputs". You can handle "update" and "clear" events in that one page, no need to specify routes for those (in frontend side). If you are creating CRUD style application, you have to create backend too to handle CREATE, UPDATE, DELETE actions.  

Here is good article about handling forms: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-build-forms-in-react/

I also recommend this library if you don't want to write all code from scratch: https://react-hook-form.com/

Comment: Thanks, 15 years of backend experience here -- almost barely any with React [Router], so yeah, I'm asking silly questions I know, but this one is specifically tied to React Router. I followed the tutorial https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/tutorial but some things are still not clicking. I think what I might need is `fetcher.Form` described in https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/tutorial#mutations-without-navigation. Then I can bin the route, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If the "clear" functionality is your only issue, you can achieve that without any external route. Try changing your code like:

```
export default function Foo() {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const textFieldRef = useRef(null);      

  function onClearClick() {
     if (confirm("Please confirm you want to clear embeddings")) {
       textFieldRef.current.value = "";
     }
  }

  return (
    <>
    <Form action="update" method="post" id="foo-form">
          <input id="label" name="label" placeholder="Label" />
          <textarea
            id="text"
            ref={textFieldRef}
            name="text"
            placeholder="Text"
            rows="5"
            cols="80"
            wrap="soft"
            required
          ></textarea>
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
          <button
              type="button"
              onClick={onClearClick}
            >
              Clear
          </button>
      </Form>
    </>
  );
}
```

So the changes would be:

- changing clear button from submit to regular button, so it won't fire submit.
- add `ref={textFieldRef}`to your textarea, this allows react to "connect" to your field (see: https://react.dev/learn/referencing-values-with-refs) this works same way as plain old `const element = getElementById('text');`

Comment: Actually it seems like you can do this by attaching custom attributes to buttons https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/action#handling-multiple-actions-per-route